# Path aliases not working in vue script block

Tags: vue.js, vite

I'm trying to completely understand the path aliases with Vue and Vite.

Outside of the `<script>` block (e.g. `<style>` and `<template>` or other .js files) absolute paths with `~` or the `@` alias, for getting the root directory are working. But inside I still need to use `../../../` for getting back to the root. If I try using `~` or `@` I get errors for files not being found.

Also wouldn't `@` and `~` do the same in that case?

EDIT:

```
// Somehow working cause it's no component but a mere .js file
import {
    filterwords
} from '@/services/signup/filterwords.js';

// Working
import passwordMeter from '../../utility/PasswordMeter.vue';
// Not working
import passwordMeter from '~/utility/PasswordMeter.vue';
import passwordMeter from '@/utility/PasswordMeter.vue';
```

Comment: Can you add a code example?

Comment: Have you set up aliases in your webpack?

`
const path = require('path');  
 module.exports = {  
 configureWebpack: {  
     resolve: {  

       alias: {  
           //aliases go here  
       },  
     },  
 }
`

Comment: @daniel I'm using vite. And no, I didn't. Doing so fired some errors. Also it's working by default as I read. And so it is, except inside the <script> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do proper changes in `vite.config.js`. Tested this locally and it solves it.
Add '~' if you also want to use that.

```
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
const path = require('path')

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  resolve:{
    alias:{
      '@' : path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
    },
  },
  plugins: [vue()]
})
```

Credit to this article: https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/import-aliases-in-vite/

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out. Also quite interesting is this: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#url-transform-rules